# Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement python==3.8.12

Tags: python, visual-studio, pip

Hi I am looking for possible solutions for the following problem. I was trying to install the requirements of a certain package, and then it gave the error of not finding a version of python(which seems to be 3.8.12), but then I also checked and made sure the version of python of my environment is 3.8.12. The code and error messages are as follows:

```
(env1) localcomp:~/User/OChemR$ pip install -r requirements.txt
**ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement python==3.8.12 (from versions: none)**
**ERROR: No matching distribution found for python==3.8.12**
(env1) localcomp:~/User/OChemR$ python --version
**Python 3.8.12**
```

The requirement.txt is included below:

## conda install:

```
python==3.8.12
opencv-python==4.5.5.62
pandas==1.4.1
numpy==1.20.3
pillow==8.4.0 
tqdm==4.62.3
rdkit==2020.09.1.0 
torchvision==0.11.3
tensorflow==2.8.0
tensorboard==2.8.0
pyqt5==5.14.1
pytorch==1.10.2
matplotlib==3.2.2
albumentations==1.1.0
flask==2.0.3
flask-wtf==1.0.0
```

Comment: could you provide the requirements.txt ?
Also just to make sure, run `python -m pip install -r requirements.txt` in case your pip is installed on another python version

Comment: you cannot install via pip a python version, which is what you're trying to do:
pip install python==3.8.12

Comment: Hi, thanks for the comment. I edited the post to include the requirements.txt. I also tried the command as suggested and got the same error message

Comment: try this ? conda install --file requirements.txt

Comment: conda install --file requirements.txt seems to work, but not all the way. The terminal gave: "The following packages are not available from current channels", and then listed some packages.

Comment: I do think you should install via pip but remove the first line

Comment: @gramschidmt please update your question with the output of `conda install`. `pip` cannot be used here, because it cannot be used to install python

Comment: remove `python==3.8.12` from file `requirements.txt`. `python` shouldn't be in this file when you use `pip`.

Answer (score 1):

Simply remove `python==3.8.12` from file `requirements.txt` when you use `pip` because `python` shouldn't be in this file when you use `pip`.